# grub2 not appearing and PC directly boots in windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I have installed xubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 dual boot but no grub is appearing and boots directly into windows 8. I have tried almost everything like boot-repair but still no grub appeared.
The details of my boot-repair are here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12657785/
my laptop is HP Pavalion G6 sku
Please somebody help

Comment: i followed installation procedure from http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

First try to change the boot order in **BIOS (UEFI) settings**.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

If this is not possible boot into Windows and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot**!

Then reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Now you can choose which operating system you want to boot from the GRUB boot loader menu.

Note :

`sda` = disk | `sda2` = efi partition | `sda7` = system partition
disk and partition numbers taken from your pastebin output

Check the partition numbers, you can identify them with **GParted**.
The (GUI) tool is already included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: Thanks for answering. my bios does not allows to change from OS boot manager to ubuntu boot manager. what should I do. I am really tired of windows and want to switch to ubuntu but I have a perticular software that works in windows only so I cannot erase windows.

Comment: @AbhinashMahor : If you really cannot change the boot order in BIOS (please check all settings again), another option is to reinstall Windows and ubuntu in mbr mode. Can you completely turn off UEFI and Secure Boot in BIOS ?

Answer (score 0):

This requires entering your bios settings and changing the boot order from "OS Loader" or possibly "Windows" to "Ubuntu" or possible "Grub" as the top priority, for further help you should look at your motherboard manual or online, usually getting into bios settings requires pressing F1, F2, or DEL on boot.

Comment: I tried but my bios does not allows to change from uefi to legacy boot. Thanks for answering.